# DITA Open Toolkit error: java.lang.StackOverflowError

Tags: java, dita, dita-ot

I am using the [DITA Open Toolkit](http://dita-ot.sourceforge.net/) to transform XML content to have different tag names. But one of my XML documents is not transforming...

```
BUILD FAILED
C:\DITA-OT\build.xml:55: The following error occurred while executing this line:

C:\DITA-OT\build.xml:86: The following error occurred while executing this line:

java.lang.StackOverflowError
```

This error happens before processing is finished. So only the first 3/4 transforms. If I remove 1/4 of the content, the transform is able to finish. (I can remove any part, the more I remove the further in the document the transform gets so I do not think its invalid tags or anything like that).

Do I need to update my configuration to allow more resources to the Java process?

Or does anyone have any ideas of how to start troubleshooting this?

Thanks!

Comment: Okay, so I mispoke a little bit in my question. Turns out that there is an XML Digital Asset being referenced that has a paragraph that is so much text that it is causing the error. If I break the text up into multiple paragraphs the transform goes. Not sure why, its not like there is a million lines of text.

Answer (score 2):

You might consider tuning the stack size via JVM parameters.  Type `java -X` at your console/terminal to see a list of them.  In this case, you're probably most interested in changing the stack size: `-Xss`.  For example, you might try `java -Xss2048k`.  If you're on Linux, you may also end up having to change your OS thread stack size with ulimit.  Typically, you would do this by adding something like `ulimit -s 2048` to /etc/profile.

If this doesn't work, try filing a bug report at http://sourceforge.net/projects/dita-ot/ or contacting the authors.

Comment: Thanks! Do you know how to get the current java stack size? I am running Windows XP 32 bit.

Comment: 320k in Java 1.6 -- from http://java.sun.com/docs/hotspot/HotSpotFAQ.html#threads_oom: "On Windows, the default thread stack size is read from the binary (java.exe). As of Java SE 6, this value is 320k in the 32-bit VM and 1024k in the 64-bit VM."